# Querying a SQLite database stored on a webserver via Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, webserver

I'm devising an application with versions on Mac OS and iOS, and I'd like some data to stay synchronized. The easiest way that I can think to do that is to store my data in a SQLite database locally on each device, store the same database on a webserver, and then run some queries on each table to synchronize the local db and the remote db.

The only piece of this puzzle I'm missing is a way to query the remote SQLite database stored on the webserver. Ideally, I'd like to do it via Objective-C, rather than marshaling data into and out of a web language like Python or JS, and without placing any other files on the webserver, like a server-side script. I'd really just like the ability to open the database on the webserver and query it via ObjC.

Is this feasible? Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Not really. Doing so would require much more effort than that would worth it. There's a reason this is generally done using PHP/Python/Ruby an JSON/XML.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is basically a C-library that keeps the database in a single file. Because of this compactness it has become the standard for storage on iOS and Mac (CoreData).

Because it had this as a design goal (as opposed to multi-user, distributed DBs like Oragle or MySQL) there is no way how you can get to DB contents over the web. The SQLite lib needs to open it as a local file.

You have these options:

- have a MySQL DB and a web API on your server (either via a service like stackmob or program yourself)
- use iCloud
- use a form of file-based synching (e.g. Dropbox or WebDAV) to keep moving around the actual SQLite file
- hybrid forms: put transactions into files that you synch and roll forward on each device

Synching is HARD. I'd just go with iCloud.

Comment: To endorse part of this answer: you cannot query SQLite over a network the way you can access most DBMSs. You must download the entire SQLite file and then access it locally. (The only exception is storing a SQLite file on a network volume accessed by something like AFP, SMB, NFS, but this method doesn't provide safe concurrent access, so it only works if you *know* the file is being accessed by only one client at a time.) You *could* essentially download the whole database, sync it up, and push the whole database back to the server, but this wouldn't support safe concurrent writes.

Comment: You **can** query MySQL directly, however. Or take the standard way, which is a middle tier. If you want to use Objective-C you can write something based on RoutingHTTPServer / CocoaHTTPServer, and even use FMDB / SQLite if you want.